# Ubuntu 22.04 - error in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, etc

After upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 There seems to be something wrong with my etc/apt/sources. When doing the `sudo apt-get update` I get a whole list of errors. I have googled but I have not found this error with ubuntu 22.04 only older or with just one line.

I did try one thing I found, but this created an error within the update about a cd-rom:

```
sudo sed -i -- 's/#deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo sed -i -- 's/# deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After trying various things the cd-rom error disappeared but I figured asking is better then trying and messing up even further.

Response to update:  **This had to many url's and looked like spam... hope the information below is enough.**

Release:

```
kornelis@Aspire7:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
kornelis@Aspire7:~$
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http ://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
```

Comment: For me the issue was something to do with the DNS it had set. 
i edited the /etc/resolve.conf file and set nameserver to 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Line 3 should be: (remove the space between `http` and `://`)

```
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
```

The last 6 lines should look like this: (remove the space between `http:` and `//`)

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted # auto generated
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that I put the spaces there because the post hat to many links

Comment: Yeah, but it results in errors ..

Comment: I only changed the post here the file on my computer doesn't have does spaces.